# Shutter Sound (Ding) recorded in video mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimagepickercontroller, video-capture

I am using a custom camera.  When I click on start record button a 'ding!' sound appears which is builtin. This results in this sound being recorded within the first second of the record.

```
-(void)overlay_start_buttonAction
{

   overlay_start_button.hidden = TRUE;
   overlay_stop_button.hidden = FALSE;
   overlay_rec_label.hidden = FALSE;
   overlay_cancel_button.hidden = TRUE;
   overlay_rotate_camera_button.hidden = TRUE;

   [image_picker startVideoCapture];

}
```

Is there a possibility to suppress this sound?

If you want to see my full code here it is http://pastie.org/5579182.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some countries have legislation, which requires mobile phones to make a sound, when recording starts. It's part of the operating system and you cannot disable or replace it.

An example is, when you try to record a phone call with or without permission of the other party. There is a sound effect at the start of the recording on purpose to notify the other party that a recording of the phone call has started.

I guess it's the same thing with video recording.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has no reference for any sound options or files. You would have to look inside the framework.

One thing you could do is create an empty - quiet sound file, give the same name and replace it in your project. I know this is not code genius, but look for the reference of the sound file name in your code and check if there is a BOOL linked to it or if it can be removed from the code.